# Three20 add TTThumbsViewController via presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I have a regular old iPhone app that has a main view controller that is loaded from a nib. I have a uibutton tied to an ibaction and when that is clicked I want to display a TTThumbsViewController. Is there a way to do that without adding a launcher or any other unnecessary overhead? A tutorial or code sample would be spectacular. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing it the standard way by initing a launcher first.